# Updating kendo angular grid to latest version using npm command

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I have a Kendo angular grid installed in my application. I have to update the Grid version from current 1.6.1 to the latest. So how to uninstall Kendo angular grid through npm command so that I can install the latest version.
For installation, I have the syntax as below. I want to uninstall.

> npm install --save @progress/kendo-angular-grid
>   @progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns @progress/kendo-angular-inputs
>   @progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs @progress/kendo-data-query
>   @progress/kendo-angular-intl @progress/kendo-angular-l10n
>   @progress/kendo-drawing @progress/kendo-angular-excel-export
>   @progress/kendo-angular-buttons

Answer (score 0):

Your install script will install the latest version.

> A package is:
>
> ```
> a) a folder containing a program described by a package.json file
> b) a gzipped tarball containing (a)
> c) a url that resolves to (b)
> d) a <name>@<version> that is published on the registry (see npm-registry) with (c)
> e) a <name>@<tag> (see npm-dist-tag) that points to (d)
> f) a <name> that has a "latest" tag satisfying (e)
> g) a <git remote url> that resolves to (a)
> ```

Check npm documentation: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

You are in the following case:

> f) a  that has a "latest" tag satisfying (e)

If you want to be explicit, you can specify latest tag which will also update all packages to the latest version.

> npm install --save @progress/kendo-angular-grid@latest
>   @progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns@latest
>   @progress/kendo-angular-inputs@latest
>   @progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs@latest
>   @progress/kendo-data-query@latest @progress/kendo-angular-intl@latest
>   @progress/kendo-angular-l10n@latest @progress/kendo-drawing@latest
>   @progress/kendo-angular-excel-export@latest
>   @progress/kendo-angular-buttons@latest

For example, you can find current tags for kendo-angular-grid here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@progress/kendo-angular-grid